# How do you convert a mysqli_result into a string?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to echo the result of a mysqli_query however I keep getting the error 'Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string' on line 'echo $result;'. 
Is there any way I can convert it into a string so that it can be echoed? (P.S sorry if this is easy, I'm new to coding.)

My database is successfully connected and the SQL statements definitely work.

```
$sql= "SELECT ImageURL FROM `unnormalisedtable` WHERE Yeargroup = 9 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1" ;

$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

echo $result;
```

The expected output is that the result of my SQLi query will be printed on screen, however the error is generated instead. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: [Read the manual and look at their examples](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: be careful using ` ORDER BY RAND()` its performance death if the table is 'large'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you limit the selection to one entry use

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['ImageURL'];
```

If you select more than one entry loop over the result.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo $row['ImageURL'];
}
```

Comment: no loop required when only 1 row\value is ever going to be returned

Comment: @tim You are right. I edited my post and added two variants.

Comment: Thanks so much this is very helpful!

Comment: @danizw if my answer solves your problem, please mark it as solved